# Is $n−m$ always the largest possible number of linearly independent vectors in this vector space?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, vector-spaces

Fix linear independent vectors $a_1, . . . , a_m ∈ \mathbb{R}^n$, and let $S$ be the vector space of such that

$S:=$ {$x∈ \mathbb{R}^n:a_i⋅x=0∀1≤i≤m$} .

The vector space $S$ always has at least $n − m$ linearly independent vectors (solutions to $a_i⋅x=0$).

Is $n−m$ always the largest possible number of linearly independent solutions or is it possible for me to find a counterexample?

Comment: Are $a_1, \dots, a_m$ linearly independent? If so, then yes. If not, no.

Comment: Yes they are. Why is that true?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the map from $R^n$ to $R^m$ defined by 
$$
v \mapsto (v \cdot a_1, v \cdot a_2, \ldots, v \cdot a_m).
$$
What does the rank-plus-nullity theorem tell you about this linear transformation?

Comment: I want to use this to prove the rank-plus-nullity theorem though.

Comment: Ah ...it would have helped if you'd mentioned that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is always true. Let $b_1,\dots,b_r$ be a basis for $S$. You can show that the set $\{a_1,\dots,a_m,b_1,\dots,b_r\}$ is linearly independent (check this), which implies that $m+r\le n$, so $r\le n-m$.

Comment: Why does it imply that?

Comment: Because you can have at most $n$ linearly dependent vectors in an $n$-dimensional vector space, and the number of vectors in that linearly independent set is $m+r$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*:For the homogeneous system $Ax=0$, there exists $n-m$ linearly independent solutions, where $n$ is the number of variables and $m$ equals to Rank($A$).